# Sum a range of cells, include every 3rd cell only if cell above hase a certain number in it

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I Am trying to make the smallest available formula to sum a range (AA17:ADB17) on to include every 3rd cell and only if cell above for instance AA4 has a certain number in it formatted like 1.0.0 , 2.0.0 , 2.1.0 which I am using this formula

```
=IF($AA$17=0,0,IF((--LEFT($AA$4,2)=GO$5),$AA$17,0))
```

and would have to repeat it in that cell 251 times which creates extremely large formula per cell.

i have used this to add up every third column and it works good but in do not know how to add only if cell above for instance AA4 has a certain number in it formatted like 1.0.0 , 2.0.0 , 2.1.0.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

i have been searching for solutions

Answer (score 1):

### Sum Up the N-th Cells In Rows

[image]

```
=LET(SumData,C5:L21,cValue,C4,Nth,3,NoCond,"Nope",
    NoDots,SUBSTITUTE(cValue,".",""),
    Cond1,LEN(cValue)=5,
    Cond2,ISNUMBER(VALUE(NoDots)),
    Cond3,SUM(--(MID(cValue,{1;3;5},1)=MID(NoDots,{1;2;3},1)))=3,
    Cond,Cond1*Cond2*Cond3,
    cs,(SEQUENCE(,INT((COLUMNS(SumData)-1)/Nth+1))-1)*Nth+1,
    dc,MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(SumData)),LAMBDA(r,
        SUM(INDEX(INDEX(SumData,r,),,cs)))),
    Res,IF(Cond,dc,NoCond),
Res)
```