# Sum every 3rd cell in a range if conditions are met for each cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a summary sheet (Detail 3) in my quoting workbook that take data from the quote detail sheet (Detail 1) (numbered 1 thru 252) then populates in each related column and also take the  group number (Up To 25 Group #) and populates that number in row 4.

I currently have this formula in cell ADE17 (Detail 2)

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(COLUMN(AA17:ADB17),3)=0,AA17:ADB17,0))
```

to add up every third cell between (AA17:ADR17). I would like to add something like this formula `IF(--LEFT($AA$4,2)=ADE$5)` which looks at only the first number in that group number in AA4 and compares it to the number in ADE5 and if it matches then AA17 is included in the sum.

Detail 1
[image: Detail 1]

Detail 2 Column letters are wrong GL will be ADB GO will be ADE
[image: Detail 2]

Detail 3
[image: Detail 3]

I have tried to combine them with no success and I am not sure if it is even possible to do what I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum a range of cells, include every 3rd cell only if cell above hase a certain number in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76745860/sum-a-range-of-cells-include-every-3rd-cell-only-if-cell-above-hase-a-certain-n)

Comment: i am sorry but that formula has me so confused.

Comment: Also instead of posting same query twice, you should reply to those who have posted answers in your last query. That would help you to understand and solve accordingly. One more thing, don't post images, instead post copiable data, by creating an example. So that when someone posts an answer you can replicate it with your original data. **[Read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**